# pgr_withpoints() How to select edges geometry till points?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, vehicle-routing-problem

I have two tables, table **poi** consist of points with point id `pid`, nearby/associated `edge_id`,`fraction` and point geometry `the_geom`. And edge table **ways** which has all the fields required(`source`, `target`, `cost`, `reverse_cost`, `the_geom`) for pgRouting.

While trying to get route from poi to poi using [pgr_withpoints()](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/src/withPoints/doc/pgr_withPoints.html), I am bit stuck with getting geometries till the poi. With the query I will get the exact cost till the poi, but I am not able to get the geometries?

```
select * from pgr_withpoints
('select id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost from ways ORDER BY id',
'select pid, edge_id, fraction, side from poi', -101, -121);
```

Now to draw lines I can join the pgr results with ways table.

```
select seq,path_seq,node,edge,pgr.cost,agg_cost,st_astext(the_geom) as geom 
from pgr_withpoints('select id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost 
from ways ORDER BY id', 'select pid, edge_id, fraction, side 
from poi', -101, -121) pgr join ways w on pgr.edge = w.id ORDER BY pgr.path_seq;
```

But since ways are `linestring` geometry, route draws till end of the edge. How can I select geometries till poi with pgr_withpoints() ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to replace the last linestring with a linestring that is split at your point.

There are a couple of ways to do this, but I'd suggest the easiest is to split `the_geom` at your end point using `ST_Split(lines.the_geom, ST_ClosestPoint(lines.the_geom, poi.the_geom))`. You could add an outer `SELECT` to your query above using `CASE WHEN` to split the linestring when `edge` is the last edge, and return the unsplit linestring otherwise.

Comment: right now I am doing the same. Splitting start and end node linestring and attaching second and first half from first and slpit line to start and end of linestring. I was expecting a single query for this. 

And pgr_withpoints() is pretty slow compared to pgr_dijkstra(). It will take around 7-8 seconds to compute. Any pointer to improve performance?